# Subclassed UIView in UITableViewCell from NIB

Tags: ios, interface-builder, nib

I created a UITableViewCell in IB that contains a custom UIView. The custom UIView is also contained in a NIB. How do I load this custom UIView into the custom UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 1):

At here, you use IB *UIView ( have class & 1 xib View to custom )*? So IB View is unnecessary, xib is view to display.

At UITableView -> add :

```
[cell getCustomView];
```

Add methods to get Customview :

```
// CustomCell.h
-(void) getCustomView;
// CustomCell.h
-(void) getCustomView{
    [customView removeFromSuperview];
    customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:customView.frame];
    [self addSubview:customView];
}
```

Add load xib CustomView:

```
// CustomView.m
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil];
        CustomView *v = (CustomView *)[nibs objectAtIndex:0];
        return v;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.  In your subclass's `initWithCoder:` method, after you've called `[super initWithCoder:aDecoder]`, you can load the other nib and add its view as a subview of the cell (`self`).

Comment: Inside - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder in the subclass of the UITableViewCell, the app crashes and cites "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CustomTableViewCell 0x1f546ec0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key titleLabel"

Comment: titleLabel is a label on the custom UIView that the cell is trying to load

Comment: Edit your question to include the full stack trace of the crash.